# how do i install "solarized-theme"?

Tags: init-file, themes, load-path

first i do this in a terminal: `$ git clone git://github.com/altercation/solarized.git`, that creates a directory in my home called "solarized", after that i add this 2 lines to my init.el

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-color-theme-solarized")`
`(load-theme 'color-theme-solarized.el t)`

so i created a directory emacs-color-theme-solarized in ".emacs.d" and i put there the code of the color-theme.., but when i "byte-compile and load"my init.el this message came in the mini-buffer: load-theme: Unable to find theme file for `color-theme-solarized.el'

what i did wrong?

Comment: Sorry for my poor skills in StackExchange, but I try to comment to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15121/23571 failing miserably. Please help me and make this better. As a comment to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15121/23571 : I needed to run `M-x package-refresh-contents` before `M-x package-install` similar to what @user66649 reported in the comments. I have a very new Emacs 26 installation and I had not used package manager before. If I did not run the `M-x package-refresh-contents` the `M-x package-install` would not have any packages to install. I guess this is common knowledge, but

Answer (score 9):

`github.com/altercation/solarized.git` is the repository for the Solarized theme for vim.

For emacs, the repo is [`https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs`](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs).

The recommended approach to install the theme is via the emacs-inbuilt package manager.

Ensure that you have the below in your emacs setup (`~/.emacs.d/init.el` by default):

```el
(require 'package)

;; Add melpa package source when using package list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

;; Load emacs packages and activate them
;; This must come before configurations of installed packages.
;; Don't delete this line.
(package-initialize)
```

- Add above to your `init.el` and restart emacs.
- Do `M-x package-install solarized-theme` (from the [Installation instructions](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs#installation) on the theme github page).
- Do `M-x load-theme` and pick one of the Solarized theme variants.

Comment: i did M-x package-install ,  but i can't find "solarized-theme"...

Comment: now i did M-x package-list-package and i found "sanitynic-solarized" and i found a bottom that said install so i did, and that works...what did i do?

Comment: 'sanityinc-solarized' is not the same. You should be able to find `solarized-theme` when you do `M-x package-list-packages` if you added Melpa to the `package-archives` list as shown above. After saving that to your `init.el`, did you restart emacs?

Comment: no, i think not, how do i restart? i closed emacs, i do not restart it

Comment: Save the above to your `init.el`, quit emacs using `C-x C-c` and then start emacs again from the terminal.

Comment: The solarized-theme tar is not available in Melpa anymore.

Comment: @kadaj I am not sure what you mean by tar. Packages from Melpa are installed using the emacs inbuilt package manager. Here is the `solarized-theme` on Melpa: https://melpa.org/#/solarized-theme

Comment: Kaushal: When you give the install command it gives an error saying that the solarized-theme-xxx.tar is not found.

Comment: Please report this [issue on Melpa's github page](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues). This looks like an intermittent issue. I wouldn't phrase it as *not available in Melpa anymore* :)

Comment: This worked, but I had to run `M-x package-refresh-contents` before `M-x package-install` found `solarized-theme`

Answer (score 2):

The version that works best for me is on MELPA at

```
https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs
```

In your packages install, you can install it through MELPA using this command:

```
M-x package-install solarized-theme
```

If you can't find solarized-theme, then make sure [MELPA is installed properly](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started).

Comment: i found sanitynic-solarized..is the same?

Comment: Seems like sanity is backward compatible with older versions of emacs whereas solarized-theme uses the more recent dash library.